# Kivy Buttons and Labels size based on display size

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to figure out how to make my buttons and labels fix perfectly depending on my display size. So if the phone display is different, it will always be in fixed size.

Python Code:

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class OpeningScreen(Screen):
    pass

class LoginScreen(Screen):
    pass

class SignupScreen(Screen):
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass


AppKv = Builder.load_file("App.kv")


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return AppKv


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Kv code:

```
#: import FadeTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.FadeTransition
#: import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex

#------------------------------------------------------------#

ScreenManagement:
    transition: FadeTransition()
    OpeningScreen:
    LoginScreen:
    SignupScreen:


#------------------------------------------------------------#

<OpeningScreen>:
    name: "OpeningScreen"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    Label:
        text: "Welcome"
        color: 1,1,1,1
        font_size: 45
        size_hint: 0.2,0.1
        pos_hint: {"x":0.40, "top":0.995}

    Button:
        size: 100,75
        on_release: app.root.current = "LoginScreen"
        text: "Login"
        font_size: 50
        color: 1,1,1,1
        background_color: (0,0,0,1)
        background_normal: ""
        background_down: ""
        size_hint: 0.3,0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "top":0.7}

    Button:
        size: 100,75
        on_release: app.root.current = "SignupScreen"
        text: "Sign up"
        font_size: 50
        color: 1,1,1,1
        background_color: (0,0,0,1)
        background_normal: ""
        background_down: ""
        size_hint: 0.3,0.2
        pos_hint: {"x":0.35, "top":0.4}

#------------------------------------------------------------#

<LoginScreen>:
    name: "LoginScreen"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        text: "Login In"
        color: 0,0,0,1
        font_size: 45
        size_hint: 0.2,0.1
        pos_hint: {"x":0.40, "top":0.995}

#------------------------------------------------------------#

<SignupScreen>:
    name: "SignupScreen"
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
    Label:
        text: "Sign Up"
        color: 0,0,0,1
        font_size: 45
        size_hint: 0.2,0.1
        pos_hint: {"x":0.40, "top":0.995}
```

I would really appreciate if anyone could help me with this. I was trying to find out how to do this but I couldn't

Answer (score 3):

`Button` and `Label` sizes can be set using several different approaches:

1. Use [Kivy Metrics](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.metrics.html/). You can set sizes using `dp` (for example `dp(100)`), this is a Density-independent Pixel size. There is also a `sp` (used similarly) that is Scale-independent Pixels (normally used for font sizes)
2. Use `self.texture_size`. You can set sizes using this as `size: self.texture_size`. This will make your `Button` and `Label` widgets just large enough to fit the text in it. You can add some padding by using something like:

   `width: self.texture_size[0] + dp(10)
    height: self.texture_size[1] + dp(10)`
3. Use `size_hint`. This will ensure that the `Button` and `Label` widgets take up the same percentage of your display, regardless of the device.

Don't forget to set `size_hint` to `None, None` for the first two above to work.

Comment: Thanks it helped me! Do you know how to make the buttons be right in the center of the display tho?

Comment: You can set them to be in the center of their parent by using: `pos_hint: {"center_x":0.5, "center_y":0.5}`